# Is there a way to remove horizontal highlight line and display only the vertical hightlight line?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I would like to display only the vertical highlight line for a linechart when user touches the graph. Currently it draws a reference line both horizontally and vertically. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Version 2.1.1 onwards has that support. Take a look at the link here. You can set the horizontal / vertical highlight indicators separately now on the DataSet instead of the chart object.

https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/commit/034e05997d2fad20d8b1a764b651b66483f713f4